# Best way to concatenate JavaScript files with dependencies and to output them as a module?

Tags: module, concatenation, requirejs

I know this question came up in similar variations often, but no solution seems to fully fit my needs. I have the following problem:

In development I use multiple JS files (a single file every "object"). These JS files have several dependencies within each other - some rely on others and I need to load them first. Currently I use RequireJS to load each JS file in the right order, so I define a module for each file. Fine and dandy.
But now I want to concatenate all my JS files into one big JS file which should be a module itself. I use the RequireJS optimizer r.js to do that. **My problem:** Every JS file is concatenated to a big JS file, but the module definition for each object is included to. I don't have one big module in one big file, but many modules in one big file.

After that I tried grunt for concatenating which works fine, but ignores dependencies of files. It just concatenates every file in alphabetical order or I have to hardcode the order in my gruntfile.

How can I solve this?

Just as an illustration to my problem:
I have following files (pseudo code):

```
FileA
- define FileA module
- depends on FileB
- FileA Logic

FileB
- define FileB module
- FileB Logic
```

And I want this output:

```
LibFile
- define LibFile module
- FileB Logic, FileA Logic
```

But I get this with r.js (module definition from FileA and FileB is copied):

```
LibFile
- define FileB module
- FileB Logic
- define FileA module
- depends on FileB
- FileA Logic
```

And I get this with grunt (wrong order):

```
LibFile
- FileA Logic
- FileB Logic
```

Maybe that questions is a little bit stupid, but I just can't solve this with the tools everybody seems to use...
I tried the grunt-requirejs plugin, too. But it throws several erros which I couldn't resolve.

Thank you,
Pipo

Comment: Why having them all in one file is a problem? You can use that file as a module if you used "package" paradigm to register the small ones...

Comment: Hi ZenMaster, what do you mean with "package" paradigm? I used "define(["./fileB"], function(fileB) { // some code for fileA; return fileA; });" to define my modules. But if I have multiple small modules like this in on big file and I try to load the file like this "define(["./LibFile"], function(LibFile) { // some code; });" LibFile is undefined. I can't require the big file as one module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am going to move it into an answer. Just so the code is a bit clearer.

I am doing these by memory (since I can't test it right now) so some little things may be not entirely accurate.

It depends of course on how you package your modules, but one way is to register all your smaller modules in a bigger module:

File A.js

```
define([], function() {
    // do something
    return A;
});
```

File B.js

```
define(['path/to/A'], function(A){
    // do something with A and more
    return B;
});
```

Then, you package them together:

File mylib.js

```
define(['path/to/A', 'path/to/B'], function(A, B){
    return {
        A : A,
        B : B
    }
}
```

you then can point your build profile to `mylib.js` and it will be combined into
one big file. It won't be one all-encapsulating module, but it will have an entry
module that references everything else. You then can use it like so:

```
require.config({
    paths : {
        'path/to/mylib' : 'real/path/to/mylib/on/server'
    }
});
require(['path/to/mylib'], function(Lib) {
    // do something using Lib.A or Lib.B
}
```

the one thing to pay attention to is the ID of your big module file. By default 
RequireJS build gives ID that matches physical path (from `appDir` IIRC) and you
have to match that when you load your dependency. Simply put, if your resulting
`mylib.js` file has a main module that received the name `'path/to/mylib'`, you will
have to match it and load it by the same ID (using `require.config.paths`) or play with
maps and such (some of which requires RequireJS 2.0).

**The following is the reason I asked you why would you want to do the "big module" thing**

Other thing of note is that all your inner smaller modules also receive IDs matching their
physical path and you can use these IDs when you use the big package module (so that you can access them not only through `Lib.A`) **if mylib.js has been loaded**:

```
require(['path/to/A'], function(A) {
    // do something using A
}
```

Comment: Hi ZenMaster, I didn't notice, that the modules get a default ID which matches the physical path. I can now load and use my concatenated file. Thanks.